# how to know from a code if the relationship between two classes is an aggregation or a composition?

Tags: java, aggregation, composition

I have a class `Player` and a class `Place`

```
public class Player{
  String name;
  int hp;
  Place place;

  public Player(int health){
    this.hp = health;
  }

  public void setPlace(Place p){
    this.place = p;
  }
}
```

I can only see examples about the composition in that way : in the constructor : 
`this.place = new Place();`

but what about the code above? is it aggregation or composition?

Comment: I would say if it's nullable (not in constructor) it's aggregation

Comment: If you deleted the player, would you expect the place still to exist?

Comment: depends on what are you doing it for; but I find it when modelling software it's not worthwhile descending to such detail -- calling it just association is enough IMO

Comment: @khelwood no place should die if player dies